# Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string

Tags: c#, formatting, padding, string.format

Can I use String.Format() to pad a certain string with arbitrary characters?

```
Console.WriteLine("->{0,18}<-", "hello");
Console.WriteLine("->{0,-18}<-", "hello");

returns 

->             hello<-
->hello             <-
```

I now want the spaces to be an arbitrary character.
The reason I cannot do it with padLeft or padRight is because I want to be able to construct the format string at a different place/time then the formatting is actually executed.

**--EDIT--**
Seen that there doesn't seem to be an existing solution to my problem I came up with this (after [Think Before Coding's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-str/541210#541210))
**--EDIT2--**
I needed some more complex scenarios so I went for [Think Before Coding's second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-str/541323#541323)

```
[TestMethod]
public void PaddedStringShouldPadLeft() {
    string result = string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "->{0:20:x} {1}<-", "Hello", "World");
    string expected = "->xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHello World<-";
    Assert.AreEqual(result, expected);
}
[TestMethod]
public void PaddedStringShouldPadRight()
{
    string result = string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "->{0} {1:-20:x}<-", "Hello", "World");
    string expected = "->Hello Worldxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<-";
    Assert.AreEqual(result, expected);
}
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldPadLeftThenRight()
{
    string result = string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "->{0:10:L} {1:-10:R}<-", "Hello", "World");
    string expected = "->LLLLLHello WorldRRRRR<-";
    Assert.AreEqual(result, expected);
}
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldFormatRegular()
{
    string result = string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "->{0} {1:-10}<-", "Hello", "World");
    string expected = string.Format("->{0} {1,-10}<-", "Hello", "World");
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Because the code was a bit too much to put in a post, I moved it to github as a gist:
http://gist.github.com/533905#file_padded_string_format_info

There people can easily branch it and whatever :)

Comment: I think you should make sure the string is not empty. Would it pass the test:
string.Fomat("{0}", (PaddedString)"Hello"); ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is another solution.

Implement `IFormatProvider` to return a `ICustomFormatter` that will be passed to string.Format :

```
public class StringPadder : ICustomFormatter
{
  public string Format(string format, object arg,
       IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
     // do padding for string arguments
     // use default for others
  }
}

public class StringPadderFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{
  public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
  { 
     if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        return new StringPadder();

     return null;
  }
  public static readonly IFormatProvider Default =
     new StringPadderFormatProvider();
}
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
string.Format(StringPadderFormatProvider.Default, "->{0:x20}<-", "Hello");
```

Comment: This one allows for multiple arguments to be formatted. Updated OP.

Comment: parameter for GetFormat should be (Type formatType) rather than (Type type)  I reckon.

Answer (score 13):

You could encapsulate the string in a struct that implements IFormattable

```
public struct PaddedString : IFormattable
{
   private string value;
   public PaddedString(string value) { this.value = value; }

   public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   { 
      //... use the format to pad value
   }

   public static explicit operator PaddedString(string value)
   {
     return new PaddedString(value);
   }
}
```

Then use this like that :

```
 string.Format("->{0:x20}<-", (PaddedString)"Hello");
```

result:

```
"->xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHello<-"
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking how to pad with spaces.

What you are asking is not possible using the `string.Format` alignment component; `string.Format` always pads with whitespace. See the *Alignment Component* section of [MSDN: Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

According to Reflector, this is the code that runs inside `StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider, string, object[])` which is called by `string.Format`:

```
int repeatCount = num6 - str2.Length;
if (!flag && (repeatCount > 0))
{
    this.Append(' ', repeatCount);
}
this.Append(str2);
if (flag && (repeatCount > 0))
{
    this.Append(' ', repeatCount);
}
```

As you can see, blanks are hard coded to be filled with whitespace.

Comment: It is possible with numbers .. I would think it realy stupid if it is possible with numbers and not with strings.

Comment: How is it possible with numbers?

Comment: I was kind of lying there. But you can do the following: Console.WriteLine("->{0:00000}<-", 12); That would give you ->00012<-

Comment: I see your edit there ;) Thanks for going the extra mile to check the internal code for me. Please have look at my solution in OP. Looks rather solid to me.

Comment: Who in Microsoft coded that using "num6" and "str2"? Please tell me Reflector came up with the variable naming.

Comment: @Alpha: Reflector came up with the variable naming, as it does for all local variables in release code.

Comment: This solution is bad and slow in same time.

Comment: @watbywbarif: Huh? This isn't a solution, it's an explanation to why this isn't possible without implementing the padding yourself.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did't read carefully, and also missed slow part.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
    dim input as string = "SPQR"
    dim format as string =""
    dim result as string = ""

    'pad left:
    format = "{0,-8}"
    result = String.Format(format,input)
    'result = "SPQR    "

    'pad right
    format = "{0,8}"
    result = String.Format(format,input)
    'result = "    SPQR"
```

Comment: But it doesn't work if you need to pad using an arbitrary character. I think that is what OP is asking.