#  String.Format() question

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

When I format a string using `string.Format()`, I'd like to be able to indicate that I want the value formatted and fill a certain amount of space at the end.

For example, say I have the following:

```
string.Format("{0}", myStringValue);
```

I'd like to be able to tell the Format function to format the value, and if it's less than say 50 characters, fill it (with spaces) so it's 50 characters in length.

Can this be done?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-str

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
string.Format("{0,50}",myStringValue);
```

or

```
string.Format("{0,-50}",myStringValue);
```

Comment: Just to note, the difference is that 50 will pad the string on the left, putting the text right justified. -50 will pad the string on the right, making the text left justified.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
string.Format("{0}", someString).PadLeft(50, ' ');
```

or

```
string.Format("{0}", someString).PadRight(50, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps have a look at this post:

[Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-str/541323#541323)