# Pad string with leading zeroes with values that are already strings?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, string.format

```
string n = string.Format("{0:000}-{1:00}-{2:00}-{3:00}-{4:000000}-{5:000000}"
                        ,"20G","34","41","1","3G","2004");
```

The above works if the values are int's but in this case they can't be.  Is it possible to do padding with string values in string.Format or do I have to do something like:

```
string n = string.Format("{0}","20G".PadLeft(3,'0'));
```

Comment: Check out IFormating for string.Format in the post [Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-st

Comment: Probably you can use a [Custom Format Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7(v=vs.100).aspx). But I doubt of the usefulness of this approach against the simple PadLeft/Right

Comment: Is this no option? `string n = string.Format("{0:000}G-{1:00}-{2:00}-{3:00}-{4:000000}G-{5:000000}" ,20,34,41,1,3,2004);`. Convert a number to a string as late as possible. I assume that you've mixed it with another information too early here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - That is not an option because the letter is not always G and it is optional and they have to be passed in as strings, not ints.