# How to add zeros to the left of a number in C#

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code for converting a Decimal number into base 3

```
 string base3 ;//= new char[textBox1.TextLength];
        for (int t = 0; t < textBox1.TextLength; t++) {
            int ascii =int.Parse( new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.Substring(t,1)).SelectMany(b => b.ToString()).ToArray()));
            base3=(ConvertToBase(ascii, 3));


            textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:000000}", base3);//for example, a returns 1211 but i nees 001211
```

So the number that it echos is 101 and it has 3 digits. but I what it to echos is 000101 so that it has 6 digits. Converting Decimal into base 3 with always 6 digits even though it has only 3 or 4 useful digits, is my goal! how can I solve it ?
current code doesn't work and duplicate Qs doesn't help

Comment: What is ConvertToBase?

Comment: The most elegant solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-st

Comment: @Steve it's an function to convert from base 10 to 3

Comment: Where is the closing brace in that code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var padded = base3.PadLeft(6, char.Parse("0"));
```

Comment: Try now, I think it needed to be a char. [see msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)