# How to format the string properly?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I have a message where I print out the Name of the Entity and Its Count. I have used `StringBuilder` class. I have code like this:

```
   message.AppendFormat("Items1:    {0}",item1count).AppendLine();
   message.AppendFormat("Items2Byb:    {0}",item2count).AppendLine();
   message.AppendFormat("Items3STCDEE:    {0}",item3count).AppendLine();
   message.AppendFormat("Items4HTECEEGG:    {0}",item4count).AppendLine();
   message.AppendFormat("ItemsASSTEC:    {0}",item5count).AppendLine();
```

The result is coming out like this:

```
  Items1:         1
  Items2Byb:         3
  Items3STCDEE           5
```

What I want is the proper alignment, no matter what the length of the Item name is:

```
      Items1:            1
      Items2Byb:         3
      Items3STCDEE       5
```

Comment: Throw in a tab or two (\t)

Comment: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-st)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach without using `PadRight` which assumes that the maximum length of the label on the left is `20`. Naturally, you should adjust the number up to be `1 + max`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class P{
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}","Items1:",1).AppendLine();
        message.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}","Items2Byb:",2).AppendLine();
        message.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}","Items3STCDEE:", 3).AppendLine();
        message.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}","Items4HTECEEGG:",4).AppendLine();
        message.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}","ItemsASSTEC:",5).AppendLine();
        Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Items1:             1
Items2Byb:          2
Items3STCDEE:       3
Items4HTECEEGG:     4
ItemsASSTEC:        5
```

Comment: I am not getting the respective results, it's just pushing the numbers to the right. I don't know why?

Comment: @c_sharp are you using exactly the format string above with no extra spaces?

Comment: @C_sharp, Also the number you need might be larger than `20`, depending on how long your longest label string is.

Answer (score 4):

For simple formatting you can use `PadRight` (using literal `1,3,4` for simplicity)

```
var message = new StringBuilder();
int width = 20;

message.Append("Items1:".PadRight(width) + 1).AppendLine();
message.Append("Items2Byb:".PadRight(width) + 3).AppendLine();
message.Append("Items3STCDEE:".PadRight(width) + 4).AppendLine();
message.Append("Items4HTECEEGG:".PadRight(width) + 5).AppendLine();
message.Append("ItemsASSTEC:".PadRight(width) + 6).AppendLine();
```

will print:

```
Items1:             1
Items2Byb:          3
Items3STCDEE:       4
Items4HTECEEGG:     5
ItemsASSTEC:        6
```

Or you can define custom method (to know more about `{0,-20}` format consider [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format). Essentially it stated to pad white-spaces from right until the string occupy 20 characters long. ):

```
public void AddLine(StringBuilder builder, string name, int val)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0,-20}{1}", name, val).AppendLine();
}
```

and reuse it like:

```
AddLine(message, "Items1:", 1);
AddLine(message, "Items2Byb:", 3);
AddLine(message, "Items3STCDEE:", 4);
AddLine(message, "Items4HTECEEGG:", 5);
AddLine(message, "ItemsASSTEC:", 6);
```