# How to pad right with zeros using string.format while using dynamic formats?

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I have the illustrative code below. I need the output for condition1 to be right justified and padded with zeros like |1234500000| instead of |0000012345| instead of  and with fixed width of 10. The format string is conditional meaning there can be one of many possible format strings depending on some criteria while there's only one line for output. Therefore functions like PadRight and PadLeft can't be used with value unless there's a way to use them while still having the same output line. (.NET 4.5)

How can I get |1234500000| while satisfying those requirements?

```
string format;

if (condition1)
format = "|{0:0000000000}|";
else
if (condition2)
format = "|{0}|";
//more conditions here
Int64 value = 12345;
string a = String.Format(format, value);
a.Dump();
```

Comment: how exactly would you know if any of the last set of numbers was supposed to be 0 when you are padding them with zeros?  seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: What do you mean? The zeros are left justified so the number starts from the first non zero digit. Numbers don't start with a zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-st)

Comment: Why would you want to pad right (with zeros) on an integer?  Wouldn't that invalidate the number?

Comment: that is not what your questions states "padded with zeros like |1234500000| instead of |0000012345|"

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: If you really meant to have a number left-padded with zeros and not otherwise, then the code you have works perfectly well. What other formats are there that make your code unusable?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ It was an edit to someone's edit and that flipped the question. It's been reverted.

Comment: @phillip It's an account number which never ends in zeros. It's probably an odd business rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only so many built-in and customizable string formats. Perhaps you could set up a different formatting function for each condition, then invoke it later:

```
Func<Int64, String> formatter;
if (condition1) 
{
    formatter = (number) => number.ToString().PadRight(10, '0');
}
else if (condition2) 
{
    formatter = (number) => number.ToString();
}

Int64 sample = 12345;
string output = string.Format("|{0}|", formatter(sample));
output.Dump();
```

Another option would be to create your own custom string format providers by implementing `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter`. For example, here's a sloppy one that would do the right padding:

```
public class RightPaddedStringFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    private int _width;

    public RightPaddedStringFormatter(int width) 
    {
        if (width < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width");

        _width = width;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // format doubles to 3 decimal places
        return arg.ToString().PadRight(_width, '0');
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) ? this : null;
    }
}
```

Then you could use your conditions to pick a formatter, e.g.:

```
IFormatProvider provider;
if (condition1)
{
    provider = new RightPaddedStringFormatter(10);
}
...

Int64 sample = 12345;
string output = string.Format(provider, "|{0}|", sample);
output.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied from the [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541098/pad-left-or-right-with-string-format-not-padleft-or-padright-with-arbitrary-st) above and it looks similar to Cory's answer.  This allows you to string.Format and pad on either side with any character whether it is a 0 or an X it is left to the formatter.

Written with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

```
void Main()
{
    var val = 12345;
    string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "{0:20:0}", val).Dump();
    string.Format(new PaddedStringFormatInfo(), "{0:-20:0}", val).Dump();
}

public sealed class PaddedStringFormatInfo : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (typeof(ICustomFormatter).Equals(formatType)) return this;

        return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Argument cannot be null");
        if (format == null) return arg.ToString();

        string[] args = format.Split(':');
        if (args.Length == 1) String.Format("{0, " + format + "}", arg);

        int padLength = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(args[0], out padLength)) throw new ArgumentException("Padding length should be an integer");

        switch (args.Length)
        {
            case 2: // padded format
                if (padLength > 0)  return (arg.ToString()).PadLeft(padLength, args[1][0]);

                return (arg.ToString()).PadRight(padLength * -1, args[1][0]);

            default: // use default string.format
                return string.Format("{0," + format + "}", arg);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
00000000000000012345
12345000000000000000
```