# Format a number using "figure space" \u2007?

Tags: c#, unicode, string-formatting

Normally string.Format() uses space characters (\u0020) as leading spaces while formatting numbers. Because space characters are smaller than digits, the width of the graphical representation of the string varies with the number of spaces.

Is there any way to tell string.Format() to use "figure space" (\u2007) instead of "space" (\u0020), so that the width of the string will be independent of the number of spaces?

I dont't like to append .Replace(' ', '\u2007') at every string.Format().

Example (same effect at html):
normal spaces: `string.Format("{0,8:F1}\r{1,8:F1}", x, y)`
 12345.6
     7.8
figure spaces: `string.Format("{0,8:F1}\r{1,8:F1}", x, y).Replace(' ', '\u2007')`
 12345.6
     7.8

Comment: Can you provide some inputs, actual outputs and expected outputs? Also the code that does the formatting, of course.

Comment: Are you refering to trailing spaces in order to right align numbers in a column, or spaces used a group separator?

Comment: At Unicode there are many different space characters like "SPACE" (U+0020) for text and "FIGURE SPACE" (U+2007) for numbers. The advantage of FIGURE SPACE is that it has the same width than the digits 0...9 of the same font. At most fonts normal SPACE is smaller than the Digits. Therefore any number should be formatted using FIGURE SPACE instead of SPACE.

Comment: @RalfCasperson every data engineer hates people that use such *non*-spaces because they make parsing their files a pain. *Layout* and *alignment* are the job of reporting tools, not text manipulation. You're asking about a very special case here - you want to do layout in text, and you want to use your own padding character. That's covered by [String.PadLeft(Int32,Char)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_)

Comment: @RalfCasperson another possibility is to create your own FormatProvider as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541323/134204). Creating custom formatters is documented in [How to: Define and Use Custom Numeric Format Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-define-and-use-custom-numeric-format-providers)

Comment: Nothing that String.Replace() cannot do.  But do pick the right font first.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the spaces for padding is hardcoded.

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs,1766

You can use things like `x.ToString("F1").PadLeft(8, '\u2007')`